# Errors usando PREG_MATCH

Tags: php

Eu criei um formario onde envia  informaçoes.

Eu penso que falta algum caracter no PREG MATCH, pois ele nao aceita o TEXTO

TEXTO

```
OPEL ASTRA G 1.4 v1999

Lado esquerdo condutor(frente esq).

Elevador Original e Completo.
- Inclui Motor e restante.
- Elevador de 2º mão

Encontra-se a funcionar.
*Não nos responsabilizamos por defeitos futuros no artigo.
```

PHP

```
if (!preg_match('#^[a-zÃ -Ã¿0-9\-+, .\#*()\\/]+$#i', $ads_description)) {
```

O que falta no PREGMATCH?

Comment: Caro Snoopy12 não dá para entender o problema da sua pergunta, não dá nem para entender o que deseja de fato que o teu preg_match faça, é uma validação? Poderia editar a pergunta para explicar melhor o que espera que este script faça?

Comment: o que o preg match ai tem é.. Se o Texto $ads_description, não tiver isto "'#^[a-zÃ -Ã¿0-9\-+, .\#*()\\/]+$#i'" da erro! O problema é que isto "'#^[a-zÃ -Ã¿0-9\-+, .\#*()\\/]+$#i'" falta algo...

Comment: Posso ter esquecido de adicionar algum caracter que o texto tenha.

Comment: Verifique isso sff!~´

Comment: Bem, estou tentando ajudar, mas realmente esse método de validação que você propos é bem ineficaz, fora que hora textos tem acentos e outra hora não, da forma que você fez o preg_match obriga a ter todos caracteres especificados, sendo que isso não deveria ser obrigação, afinal nenhum texto é igual ao outro, por exemplo, o teu regex OBRIGA a ter o `¿`, mas o teu texto não tem, entáo obviamente vai falhar.

Comment: Então como faço para que ele aceite estes caracteres como (a-Z, á 0-9, \-+, .\#*()\\/)

Comment: Eu quero enviar um texto onde aceite tudo menos "< > « » ' & #"

Answer (score 1):

Seu "método" de validação proposto **é bem ineficaz**.

Entenda que que hora textos tem acentos e certos caracteres e **outra hora não**, da forma que você fez o `preg_match` **obriga** a ter todos caracteres especificados, sendo que isso não deveria ser obrigação, afinal nenhum texto é igual ao outro, por exemplo, o teu regex **OBRIGA** a ter o `¿`, mas o teu texto não tem, então obviamente vai falhar.

Regex não é só copiar e colocar, regex não é como programação, em programação as vezes você escreve um código ruim que funciona, em regex se você não entender o básico provavelmente vai tudo falhar mesmo, eu vou dizer é raro as pessoas que entendem mesmo de regex, aqui no site tem diversas respostas com regex com problemas, sim pessoas que respondem usando regex e dão soluções problematicas.

Eu não estou querendo criticar essas pessoas, mas sim explicar que regex é algo complicado, não é como escrever um `hello world` se pular o básico disso vai dar problema sim, sua intenção provavelmente é só validar se tem um destes caracteres, mas você usou as seguintes expressões:

- `^` Casa o começo da cadeia de caracteres
- `+` Busca até a proxima expressão (no caso do seu o proximo é o `$`)
- `$` Casa o fim da cadeia de caracteres ou a posição logo antes da quebra de linha do fim da cadeia

Então em `^[a-zÃ -Ã¿0-9\-+, .\#*()\\/]+$`, o `^` e `+$` estão obrigando a sua string ser composta inteiramente de: `a-zÃ -Ã¿0-9\-+, .#*()\/`, ou seja vai falar tudo, fora que tem muitos problemas nessa expressão, eu sinceramente estou tentando endender o porque você fez isso: `Ã -Ã¿`, isso simplesmente não funciona, parece que você copiou de algum lugar essa regex, mas o tal lugar estava com problema de unicode mistura com latin1 que acabou convertendo os acentos e falhou tudo.

Eu vou repetir, quer usar regex, aprenda o básico, regex é uma coisa que raramente vai funcionar ber na base do Ctrl+C.

Bem vamos ao que importa, provavelmente você quer validar `a-z` e letras acentuadas, você também quer validar uma série de caracteres e pontuação, então vamos separar tudo que é necessário:

- Caracteres necessário:  `<`, `>`, `«`, `»`, `'`, `&`, `*`, `#`, `?`, `!`, `.`, `+`, `\`, `-`, `(`, `)`, `º`, `\` e `/` (qualquer coisa é só adicionar mais), seria algo como `[<>«»\'&*\#?!.+\-()º\\/]`
- De A a Z de 0 a 9, seria algo como `[a-z0-9]`
- Espaços, TABs e quebra de linhas seria o `\s`
- Acentos `\p{L}` (requer o modificador `u`)

Pronto este é o basico dos seus caracteres, agora basta mesclar tudo em algo como (note que adicionei o modificador `u` que é para unicode, o `i` é para case-insentive):

```
'^[<>«»\'&*\#?!.+\-()º\\/a-z0-9\p{L}\s]+$#ui'
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
<?php

$data = 'OPEL ASTRA G 1.4 v1999

Lado esquerdo condutor(frente esq).

Elevador Original e Completo.
- Inclui Motor e restante.
- Elevador de 2º mão

Encontra-se a funcionar.
*Não nos responsabilizamos por defeitos futuros no artigo.';

var_dump( preg_match('#^[<>«»\'&*\#?!.+\-()º\\/a-z0-9\p{L}\s]+$#iu', $data) );
```

Comment: ok mas uso if(!preg match ou if(pregmatch  , com ou sem o !?

Comment: Caro @Snoopy12 não existe `pregmatch` aprenda o básico com a documentação do php: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php - eles mostram o uso básico de todas funções e os nomes corretos, editei a resposta com o um exemplo, como EU DISSE NO FINAL DA RESPOSTA: "Estou editando a resposta...", agora que terminei a edição pode analisar.

Comment: deu erro: Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 4 in /var/www/html/inc/creator/class_create_ads.php on line 146

Comment: @Snoopy12 teu documento esta salvo como? Utf-8 ou ANSI?